# messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler not receiving messages in web

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm implementing firebase notifications in web application. I'm unable to receive background notifications when web page is not active.

What I have done so far is:

1. Created `manifest.json` in root directory with code:
   `{   "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507" }`
2. Created file `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in root directory with following code:

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');
    
    firebase.initializeApp({
        'messagingSenderId': '11111'
    });
    
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    
    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
        //sometime receive notification in this
        debugger;
        //some code here to receive notification..
        return self.registration.showNotification(title,
            notificationOptions);
    });
```

3. In `Home/Index` page put following code to get permissions and token

```js
firebase.initializeApp({
            'messagingSenderId': '11111'
        });
        
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        
        messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
            console.log('Notification permission granted.');

            messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {

                if (currentToken) {
                    console.log(currentToken);
                    sendTokenToServer(currentToken); //save in database
                }
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
            });
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
        });
        
        messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
            messaging.getToken().then(function(refreshedToken) {
                sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
            }).catch(function(err) {
            });
        });
        
                messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
            //receive notification here when this page is active. working fine

        });
```

4. Send notification from postman
   [image]

> How can I receive notifications in
>   messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler?

Answer (score 0):

The above code mentioned in question is fine. Issue was with the `app focus`. 
Lets say I have pages p1, p2 and p3.

p1 has code to get notification permission, get token and receive foreground notifications.
I was expecting background notifications on page p2 and p3.

But these two pages will receive notification in `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler` only if they are not in currently focused tab of browser.